# Enabling a parameter in a field map in a Python script

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters, tool-validation

I am creating a customized version of the Find Identical tool in Python. The script works just fine, but there's one thing that I can't seem to figure out.

In the standard ESRI Find Identical tool, the optional XY tolerance and Z tolerance parameters are disabled unless you choose the "Shape" field as the field you want to find identical values in. Then they become enabled. I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Python. I know this involves customizing behavior in the validation tab under properties, but all of the examples I've seen online show this for values and not something in a field map:

```
if self.params[3].value == "Get Spatial Weights From File": 
    self.params[8].enabled = True  
else:
    self.params[8].enabled = False
```

This code doesn't work for the field map. Is there a way to enable these parameters if "Shape" is selected in the field map?

Comment: So, are you not trying to enable/disable a parameter in the tool dialog, based on the user's selection for another parameter? That example code you gave does exactly that. So what does a field map have to do with any of this?

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. The problem is that code for me doesn't work if the parameter is a field map, like in the Find Identical tool. I have tried it on a parameter where the user has to type in a value, and it works.